# How can I prove that the elements form the symmetric group $S_4\ $?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

How can I prove that the elements

$$x^j\cdot y^l\cdot x\cdot y^k$$

with $x=(12)$ , $y=(1234)$ , $0\le j \le 1$ , $0\le l\le 2$ , $0\le k\le 3$ form the symmetric group
$S_4$ ?

Is should be enough to show that the elements are pairwise different, but how
can I do this by hand ?

Comment: You can always carry out those $2 \times 3 \times 4 = 24$ multiplications by hand. Is this not what you had in mind?

Comment: No, I would like to have a shorter method. By the way, is it really enough to show that the elements are pairwise different ?

Comment: Yes, because $24$ is the order of the group.

Comment: How do you know it is true if you haven't checked it already?

Comment: I have checked it with GAP.

Comment: Maybe the relations $x^2=y^4=(xy)^3=e$ help for the prove.

Comment: So why do you want to do it by hand? (I can't see any obvious way of simplifying the calculation, and with a problem like this I would trust a computer calculation more than a hand calculation!)

Comment: If I calculate the sets $x^j\cdot y^l$ and $x\cdot y^k$, can I show then easily that the products arising from these sets are pairwise different ?

Comment: @DerekHolt by the way : How can I use GAP to get a presentation of a group with given generators ? For example , a presentation of $S_4$ with the generators $(12)$ and $(1234)$ ?

Comment: @Peter: In GAP,`RelatorsOfFpGroup(Range(IsomorphismFpGroupByGenerators(Group(x,y),[x,y])));` gives you a set of defining relators in suitably defined x and y.  (e.g. $x^2$, $y^4$, $(x/y)^3$)